# Использовать интерпретатор Питон без установки (или с сетевого диска)

Tags: python, windows

Добрый день.
Я написал полезный и сильно необходимый скрипт на Питоне для своего отдела, но интерпретатор (в виде Анаконды) Питона установлен только на моем ПК. 
Так как в нашей организации очень развита бюрократия, устанавливать Питон каждому сотруднику - очень долгая и нудная задача, на которую могут уйти месяцы.

Подкиньте идею, как запускать ру-скрипты на соседних компах?

Будет ли работать интерпретатор, если его просто скопировать с моего компа на соседние компы?

P.S. на компах стоит windows 7x64, пипка не работает.

Comment: Посмотрите вот здесь архивы embeddable: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ . По сути это как раз "портативный" вариант Python, который можно просто распаковать, и все будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо. Можно попробовать через начальника затащить архивчик. У него USB порты работают

Comment: Да, и судя по всему в файле `python36._pth` можно прописать пути к модулям (там по-умолчанию `python36.zip` и `.`), по идее если нужны будут какие-то дополнительные модули, то можно их прямо в эту же папку скидывать.

Comment: Вы вероятно хотите py2exe или pyinstaller итд, чтобы упаковать ваш скрипт со всеми зависимостями, включая сам python, в один исполняемый файл/папку.

Answer (score 2):

Скопировать папку `C:\Python` на соседние компы и `py` скрипт запускать через консоль Windows командой `C:\Python\python.exe D:\script.py`. Работает, проверено.

Answer (score 2):

1. Распаковать архив с питоном
2. Прописать соответствующий путь в path

Comment: Йо-хо-хо! Обои даже на компе поменять нельзя, а вот path доступна для изменения! Вот это поворот :)

Comment: @Skotinin, path'ов два - один системный, а второй - пользовательский. Вроде он всегда доступен, не?

Comment: все так. Системный закрыт, пользовательский открыт. У нас компы огорожены по самую шею, поэтому удивился, что свойства системы вообще открылись.